# Find current connected USB storage path in C++

Tags: windows, qt, winapi, mingw

My Env:

```
Qt 5.3.1
Windows 10
```

I need to find the path of mounted USB storage devices.
Through the path, I can copy the files via Qt.
I know there is a cross-platform `libusb`. But want to know any simple solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to get removable drives:

```
void EnumUsbDrives() {
    DWORD drv = ::GetLogicalDrives();
    if (drv == 0) return;

    DWORD mask = 1;
    TCHAR szDrive[] = _TEXT("?:\\");

    for (uint_t i = 0; i < ('Z' - 'A' + 1); i++, mask <<= 1) {
        if (drv & mask) {
            szDrive[0] = (TCHAR)(_T('A') + i);
            if (::GetDriveType(szDrive) == DRIVE_REMOVABLE) {
                bool bUSB = IsDriveUSB(szDrive);
                if (bUSB) {
                    // Time do to something useful
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Function IsDriveUSB is a bit more complicated. I have teared it from an in-house library; the function uses custom helper classes xregistry and xstring_nocase. Their purpose is pretty obvious, I believe you will have no trouble replacing it with other similar classes or API calls.

```
bool IsDriveUSB (LPCTSTR szDrive) throw() {
    TCHAR szLogicalDrive[] = _TEXT("\\\\.\\x:");
    szLogicalDrive[4] = szDrive[0];
    HANDLE hDrive = ::CreateFile(szLogicalDrive, FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
    if (hDrive == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return false;       // Can't open drive so we have to assume the drive is fixed

    VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS vde;
    DWORD dwBytesReturned = 0;
    BOOL br = ::DeviceIoControl(hDrive, IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS, NULL, 0, &vde, sizeof(vde), &dwBytesReturned, NULL);
    ::CloseHandle(hDrive);
    if (!br) return false;      // Can't get extents info so we have to assume the drive is fixed

    if (vde.NumberOfDiskExtents != 1) return false;
    ULONG uPhysDrive = vde.Extents[0].DiskNumber;
    TCHAR szPhysDrive[16];
    _stprintf(szPhysDrive, _TEXT("%u"), uPhysDrive);

    try {
        xregistry rk(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, OS.Is64bit());
        rk.open(_TEXT("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\services\\Disk\\Enum"), KEY_QUERY_VALUE);
        if (!rk.value_exists(szPhysDrive)) return false;
        xstring_nocase strInterface = rk.get_string(szPhysDrive).substring(0, 7);
        return strInterface == _TEXT("USBSTOR");
    }
    catch (...) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first we need enumerate all devices which support interface [`GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/guid-devinterface-disk). then we can open file on this interface and query for it [`STORAGE_ADAPTER_DESCRIPTOR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff800832(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff800835(v=vs.85).aspx) and look for

> **BusType**
>
> Specifies a value of type [`STORAGE_BUS_TYPE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff800833(v=vs.85).aspx) that indicates the
>   type of the bus to which the device is connected.

for usb this will be `BusTypeUsb`

```
static volatile UCHAR guz;

CONFIGRET EnumUsbStor()
{
    CONFIGRET err;

    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);
    ULONG BufferLen = 0, NeedLen = 256;

    union {
        PVOID buf;
        PWSTR pszDeviceInterface;
    };

    for(;;) 
    {
        if (BufferLen < NeedLen)
        {
            BufferLen = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca((NeedLen - BufferLen) * sizeof(WCHAR)), stack) / sizeof(WCHAR);
        }

        switch (err = CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW(const_cast<PGUID>(&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK), 
            0, pszDeviceInterface, BufferLen, CM_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_LIST_PRESENT))
        {
        case CR_BUFFER_SMALL:
            if (err = CM_Get_Device_Interface_List_SizeW(&NeedLen, const_cast<PGUID>(&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK), 
                0, CM_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_LIST_PRESENT))
            {
        default:
            return err;
            }
            continue;

        case CR_SUCCESS:

            while (*pszDeviceInterface)
            {
                BOOLEAN bIsUsb = FALSE;
                HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(pszDeviceInterface, 0, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

                if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                {
                    STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY spq = { StorageAdapterProperty, PropertyStandardQuery }; 
                    STORAGE_ADAPTER_DESCRIPTOR sad;

                    ULONG n;
                    if (DeviceIoControl(hFile, IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY, &spq, sizeof(spq), &sad, sizeof(sad), &n, 0))
                    {
                        bIsUsb = sad.BusType == BusTypeUsb;
                    }
                    CloseHandle(hFile);
                }

                pszDeviceInterface += 1 + wcslen(pszDeviceInterface);
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

also we can look for *EnumeratorName* in interface string - are this is `USBSTOR`. fast end simply:

```
wcsstr(_wcsupr(pszDeviceInterface), L"\\USBSTOR#");
```

search for `\USBSTOR#` substring in interface name. or more correct - get `Device_InstanceId` from interface name and query it for [`DEVPKEY_Device_EnumeratorName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/devpkey-device-enumeratorname)

```
CONFIGRET IsUsbStor(DEVINST dnDevInst, BOOLEAN& bUsbStor)
{
    ULONG cb = 0, rcb = 256;

    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);
    DEVPROPTYPE PropertyType;

    CONFIGRET status;

    union {
        PVOID pv;
        PWSTR EnumeratorName;
        PBYTE pb;
    };

    do 
    {
        if (cb < rcb)
        {
            rcb = cb = RtlPointerToOffset(pv = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
        }

        status = CM_Get_DevNode_PropertyW(dnDevInst, &DEVPKEY_Device_EnumeratorName, &PropertyType,
            pb, &rcb, 0);

        if (status == CR_SUCCESS)
        {
            if (PropertyType == DEVPROP_TYPE_STRING)
            {
                DbgPrint("EnumeratorName = %S\n", EnumeratorName);
                bUsbStor = !_wcsicmp(L"USBSTOR", EnumeratorName);
            }
            else
            {
                status = CR_WRONG_TYPE;
            }

            break;
        }

    } while (status == CR_BUFFER_SMALL);

    return status;
}

CONFIGRET IsUsbStor(PCWSTR pszDeviceInterface, BOOLEAN& bUsbStor)
{
    ULONG cb = 0, rcb = 256;

    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);
    DEVPROPTYPE PropertyType;

    CONFIGRET status;

    union {
        PVOID pv;
        PWSTR DeviceID;
        PBYTE pb;
    };

    do 
    {
        if (cb < rcb)
        {
            rcb = cb = RtlPointerToOffset(pv = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
        }

        status = CM_Get_Device_Interface_PropertyW(pszDeviceInterface, &DEVPKEY_Device_InstanceId, &PropertyType, pb, &rcb, 0);

        if (status == CR_SUCCESS)
        {
            if (PropertyType == DEVPROP_TYPE_STRING)
            {
                DbgPrint("DeviceID = %S\n", DeviceID);

                DEVINST dnDevInst;

                status = CM_Locate_DevNodeW(&dnDevInst, DeviceID, CM_LOCATE_DEVNODE_NORMAL);

                if (status == CR_SUCCESS)
                {
                    status = IsUsbStor(dnDevInst, bUsbStor);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                status = CR_WRONG_TYPE;
            }

            break;
        }

    } while (status == CR_BUFFER_SMALL);

    return status;
}
```