# Write to device directly in QT

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I want to write some iso file to flash drive, I've tried this:

```
Qfile file(":/myiso.iso");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QFile dest("\\.\PysicalDrive1");
dest.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
while(!file.atEnd()) {
    dest.write(file.read(512));
}
dest.close();
file.close();
```

But after running this code nothing happend to drive D (the flash disk I've mounted)
How could I copy iso to flash disk in Windows with qt?

Comment: What is the reason you write a program for it? There are already a lot of programs which can write directly to a USB drive, and make them bootable (which writing a raw CD/DVD ISO might not be able to do). What specific problem is your programs supposed to solve, that others can't?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've developed a program that has some part that should load some customzed linux iso to flash and end user are not experinced, so I prefer to write iso to flash inside my app and not use third party program for this task.

Comment: Please show the *real* code.  The code shown has at least one typo and doesn't [open](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#open) either `file` or `dest`.

Comment: Are you going to copy a file to USB storage? If yes, duplicated with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49025845/find-current-connected-usb-storage-path-in-c)

Comment: @Jiu any kind of storage but usually USB storage

Comment: @Aryan you can use `QDir::drives()` or Windows API `GetLogicalDrives` to find available drives, base on the drive type `GetDriveType`, find out the path of the drive which you want.

Answer (score 1):

[QFile](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html) cannot represent the disk drive device. If interested in development of own low-level disk read-write utility you should derive your own class from [QIODevice](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html) which is a (grand)parent to `QFile`.

The principles or even better working code for that you may find in projects like [libburnia](https://www.google.com/search?q=Libburnia) or libburn (I used to look at that code).