# get a list of devices attached to my computer using Qt API

Tags: c++, windows, qt

When I connect a camera of phone to my computer via USB, I can see it listed in the list of devices (together with drives) in Windows File Explorer. Is there a way to get the list of devices with Qt API? I know I can get the drives using `QStorageInfo::mountedVolumes()` but this does not return the external devices. Any ideas?

Comment: You might find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29414329/5366641

Comment: Hi @V.K., you can find a discussion in [Qt Forums here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/78039/transfer-files-from-qt-creator-to-external-usb-port/4), you will find is a code snippet using _foreach (const QStorageInfo &storage, QStorageInfo::mountedVolumes())_ that can help you check if you have a bug in your code, as I believe external USB devices should be listed. Another option to enumerate all USB devices, and maintain support for multiple platforms, may be using [LibUSB](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__dev.html). The link has a code snippet as well.

Comment: Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49025845/find-current-connected-usb-storage-path-in-c